# How this function execute in details?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I don't understand how this function executes. Can someone explain it to me please? I understand first step: if 
    `n<=0`  then function stops executing.

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n];
  }
}

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4], 1));
```

Why is the result 5? I want someone to explain how function executes.

Comment: The function executes twice, with n = 1 (initial value) and with n = 0. So it recursively sums the 0th and 1st elements of the array, which are 2 + 3 = 5.

Comment: `sum([2,3,4],1) = sum([2,3,4], 0) + [2,3,4][1] = [2,3,4][0] + [2,3,4][1] = 2 + 3 = 5`

Answer (score 0):

This is going to recursively call the `sum` function and sum all the numbers from `arr[n]` down to `arr[0]`.

We can simply replace and unfold the (effective) function calls to examine what's happening:

```
sum([2, 3, 4], 1)
```

The execution will go to the `else` branch of the function because `n <= 0` is `false`, so if we replace with that code, we get:

```
sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n]
```

Since we have the values of `arr`( it's `[2, 3, 4]`) and `n` ( which is `1`) we can replace those, too:

```
sum([2, 3, 4], 1 - 1) + [2, 3, 4][1]
```

Now, let's unfold the function call again. The effective call is `sum([2, 3, 4], 0)`, so this time the code would go in the `if` branch since `n <= 0` is `true` and we get:

```
[2, 3, 4][0] + [2, 3, 4][1]
```

I've also replaced the `arr` from `arr[0]` with the argument we have for it.

There are no more recursive calls to `sum`, so we are finished with the unfolding.

Now, we simply calculate - what's element zero of `[2, 3, 4]` and what's element one of `[2, 3, 4]`:

```
2 + 3
```

Finally, simple addition gives us `5`.

If it's any easier to read, here is the recursion turned into a straight loop while still keeping close to the recursive control flow:

```js
function sum(arr, n) {
  let total = 0;
  while (true){
    if (n <= 0) {
      total += arr[0];
      
      return total;
    } else {
      total += arr[n];
      n -= 1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4], 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a good read on recursion https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/demystifying-recursion-by-stack-tracing/

```
    if (n <= 0) {
        return arr[0]; //that is 2
    } else {
        //sum([2,3,4], 1-1 ) + arr[1] that is 3; //for the first time
        return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n];
    }
}
```

In the above case first call of `sum([2,3,4] , 1)` will hold the value of arr[1] in stack which is 3. after recursion call next value of n will be 0 and it will return arr[0] that is 2 and at the time of pop it will add values and result will be 5.

Answer (score 0):

This is recursion function, in order to understand the result you have to trace to code and check the STACK CALL result;

**NOTE**: since there is a return statement there is no need for if else in your code, first if is enough 
you function on first invoke call the sum again and has the value `arr[1] = 3`, then on next call stack the sum function has `sum([2,3,4], 0)` since the n =0, then it will `return arr[0]` which equal to 2; final result will be 2 + 3 = 5
[image: STACK CALL]